# Translate an array of strings using Microsoft Translator in c#

Tags: c#, xml, api, http, microsoft-translator

i'm working on a c# app that translates xml files , i parsed the xml file, extracted the strings to translate and stored them in a string array now i'm trying to send this string array through http to translate it using this :

```
/*string[] translateArraySourceTexts = GetStringArray("./Traduction/xml.xml");*/

       public static string[] GetStringArray(string file)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

        var sentences = from l in doc.Descendants("sentence") select (string)l.FirstNode.ToString();

        return sentences.ToArray();
    }

{ string[] strarr = GetStringArray("./Traduction/xml.xml");
```

/*loop to store strarr strings in translateArraySourceTexts */

```
        for (int i = 0; i < strarr.Count(); i++)
        {
         string[] translateArraySourceTexts = { strarr[i] };


string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray";
                        string body = "<TranslateArrayRequest>" +
                                         "<AppId />" +
                                         "<From>{0}</From>" +
                                         "<Options>" +
                                            " <Category xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                                             "<ContentType xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\">{1}</ContentType>" +
                                             "<ReservedFlags xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                                             "<State xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                                             "<Uri xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                                             "<User xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
                                         "</Options>" +
                                         "<Texts>" +
                                         "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{strarr[i]}</string>" +
                                         "<To>{5}</To>" +
                                      "</TranslateArrayRequest>";
                        string reqBody = string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", translateArraySourceTexts[i], to);}
```

//This is the xml file i'm using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document source="user">
    <sentences>
        <sentence lang="fr" id="123">
            salut tout le monde !
        </sentence>
        <sentence lang="fr" id="123">
            salut tout le monde !
        </sentence>
        <sentence lang="fr" id="123">
            salut tout le monde !
        </sentence>
        <sentence lang="fr" id="123">
            salut tout le monde !
        </sentence>
        <sentence lang="fr" id="123">
            salut tout le monde !
        </sentence>
    </sentences>
</document>
```

so i guess my array have to contain the sentence " salut tout le monde !" 5 times
but i dont get the full strings in response only 4, while my array contains 5

Comment: "translateArraySourceTexts[0], 
translateArraySourceTexts[1], 
translateArraySourceTexts[2], 
to"
are the string you send I guess, it seems that you send only 4 or them.
You should show us a bit more of your code

Comment: Yes i guess so but i tried to do it with a loop because in case i don't know how much strings i may have i'm going to edit the question and add more code

Comment: Can you add the loop please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed your code, it's confusing but I see your problem.
You have to get the list of your elements, then make use your loop. So  you can use :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

IEnumerable<XElement> sentences = xmlDoc.Elements("document").Elements("sentences").Elements("sentence");

foreach (XElement s in sentences)
{
    string[] translateArraySourceTexts = { strarr[i] };

    string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray";
    string body = 
        "<TranslateArrayRequest>" +
         "<AppId />" +
         "<From>{0}</From>" +
         "<Options>" +
            " <Category xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
             "<ContentType xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\">{1}</ContentType>" +
             "<ReservedFlags xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
             "<State xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
             "<Uri xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
             "<User xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2\" />" +
         "</Options>" +
         "<Texts>" +
         "<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">{2}</string>" +
         "<To>{3}</To>" +
      "</TranslateArrayRequest>";
    string reqBody = string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", s.Value, to);}
}
```

Comment: Thank u,  I've tried it but it catched an exception :   System.Net.WebException: the distant server returned an error : (400) incorrect request

Comment: could you show me what you send and more of your code please?

Comment: Thank u Ben, i've tried " for (int i = 0; i <= strarr.Count(); i++) " but i've got only one string showed